# How can i call jquery dynamic id's and sum validation in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I can add more skills by clicking +Add Skill Button
How can i validate sum to 100 by query.

I want to know how to call the id of the skills and weightage..?
[image]

My Form code is this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h4>Skills Required</h4>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <table id="jobSkills" class="col-lg-10" style="border:1px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4">Skill</td>
                    <td class="col-xs-4">Weightage</td>
                    <td class="col-xs-4">Test Type</td>
                    <td class="col-xs-4">Assign to GD-Skill</td>
                    <td class="col-xs-4">Assign to PI-Skill</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <span class="text-center btn btn-danger addSkills">+ Add Skills</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my script of addmore

```
var skillcount=0;

$(".addSkills").click(function(){
    $('#jobSkills tr:last').after('<tr>
    <td class="col-xs-4"><input class="wp-form-control searchskill" count="' + skillcount + '" name="skill[' + skillcount + '][title]" type="text" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td class="col-xs-4"><input class="wp-form-control" count="' + skillcount + '" name="skill[' + skillcount + '][weightage]" type="text" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td class="col-xs-2"><span class="removeSkill" id="' + skillcount + '" ><a style="color:red">Remove</a></span></td>
    </tr>');
    skillcount++;
    //console.log(skillcount);
});

$("#jobSkills").on('click','.removeSkill',function(){
    console.log($(this).parent());
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: can you please clearly tell the requirement since at one place it is _How can i validate sum to 100 by query._ & at another it is  _I want to know how to call the id of the skills and weightage..? _

Comment: @user2181397   yes.1. how to call the id of the skills and weightage 2.How can i validate sum to 100 by query.

Comment: use classes instead of ids to do the sum

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I Got the solution for sum:

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < skillcount; i++){
    sum += parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('skill[' + i + '][weightage]')[0].value);
}
if( sum == NaN || sum != 100){
    alert('Sum of All skill weightage must be 100');
    return false;
}
```